# Python - datetime keep timezone name as of like +02:00

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset

I have timezone aware datetime, and I need it to have format like this:

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
```

So I change it like this:

```
now_with_tz = now_with_tz.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

it prints it like this:

```
2015-10-27T13:04:08+0200
```

But I need it to have format like this:

```
2015-10-27T13:04:08+02:00
```

How can I achieve it (without altering string with slices etc if possible)?

Comment: unrelated: `%z` is a numeric utc offset. %Z is the timezone name/abbr. (though you should use the numeric offset anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is isoformat method.

```
>>> x = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 29, 10, 40, 50, tzinfo=GMT2())
>>> x.isoformat()
'2015-10-29T10:40:50+02:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this one:)